# Cant change input value with simple jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click button `.one` I want `.res` value to + 1 but it doesnt seem to work

```
$(".one").click(function(){
    $('.res').val() + 1;
})
```

```html
<input class="res" src="0">
<button class="one">1</button>
```

Comment: `.val` gets the value - don't think the src attribute is valid for an input (unless it is an image input)

Comment: Firstly, you're using the getter, not the setter. See the docs: https://api.jquery.com/val. Secondly, the `input` should have `value="0"`, not `src="0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not saving the value back into `$('.res')`. Also note that you need to use `parseInt` (or possibly `parseFloat`) to convert the string value to a number, and you should set the initial value of `$('.res')` with `value`, not `src`:

```js
$(".one").click(function(){
    $('.res').val(parseInt($('.res').val()) + 1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="res" value="0">
<button class="one">1</button>
```

Comment: Your script returns NaN

Comment: @stafilo in what situation?

Comment: My bad. Only tested by putting an actual value in there and pressing the button. Code and explanation corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You're giving the `<input>` tag a `src` of 0 when it should be `value`:

```
<input class="res" value="0">
```

The jQuery is also syntactically incorrect, consider this instead:

```
var counter = $(".res").val();
$(".one").click(function(){
    counter++;
    $(".res").val(counter);
});
```

Comment: What happens if someone types a different number in to the input?

Comment: That would apply to any of the answers given. You could simply set the textbox to `disabled="disabled"` or `readonly="readonly"` in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the value back to `res.val` - currently it's an orphaned expression:

```
$(".res").val(+($(".res").val()) + 1);
```